# How can we get a result from the following tables for a some key values , when the values can change based on user's upload

Tags: sql, database, oracle, dynamic, database-design

P1 (Master table) Cols:Teamname TeamID

```
              Data: ABC      1 
                    DEF      2
```

P2 (Fieldmapping) Cols:FieldDesc Fieldname TeamID:

```
              Data:Goals     Text1     1,
                   Player    Text2     1,
                   Shots     Text1     2,
                   Batsman   Text2     2,
                   Runs      Text3     2,
```

P3 (Values)        Cols:TeamID  text1  text2  text3 text4 text5 text6 text7 text8 text9 text10

```
              Data:  1      3   John
                     1      2   Mark
                     1      1   Stu
                     2      10  Bart   14
                     2      3   Mary   6
                     2      50  Ba     100
```

Expected Output: If the user selects the ABC then the output should be

O/p: Col: Team Goal Player

```
 Data: ABC  3   John
       ABC  2   Mark
       ABC  1   Stu
```

Expected Output: If the user selects the DEF then the output should be

```
 O/p: Col: Team Shots Batsman Runs

 Data: DEF  10   Bart    14
       DEF  3    Mary    6
       DEF  50   Ba     100
```

How can i write this in SQL ?

Comment: If you are looking for a dynamic number of columns based on user input then it is not possible with straight SQL. You have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes, looking for help on dynamic SQL. Dont have much knowledge on how that works

Comment: Dynamic SQL just means: 1. Run a query to find out what columns you want to show in your final result. 2. Build the query with those columns (you can use any programming language for this), 3. Run the final query.

Comment: Usually, though, you would just select the data in rows instead of columns and have your app or Website care about how to display the data.

Comment: And as to "you can use any programming language for this": Oracle has a programming language built into the DBMS; PL/SQL. So, if you want dynamic SQL here and you know PL/SQL then use this. If you don't know it yet, learn it or use another programming language (Java, C#, Visual Basic, PHP, whatever) that you are familiar with instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) in sql queries. Here you can join table `p1` and  table `p3` on `teamId` to get the desired results.

```
select
  teamname,
  shots,
  batsman,
  coalesce(runs, 0) as runs
from p1
join p3
on p1.teamId = p3.teamId
where teamname = 'DEF'
order by
  teamname
```

Output:

```
| teamname | shots | batsman | runs |
| -------- | ----- | ------- | ---- |
| DEF      | 10    | Bart    | 14   |
| DEF      | 3     | Mary    | 6    |
| DEF      | 50    | Ba      | 100  |
```

Comment: I know basic joins , but here you are specifying the column names. But I need the column names as dynamic based on the teamname